# Get value in object or array object php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, arrayobject

How can in php get the value name out of this object and out of this array of objects? And how can check is object or array object and then get value name?

```
"director": {
"@type": "Person",
"url": "/name/nm0001104/",
"name": "Frank Darabont"}



"director": [
{
  "@type": "Person",
  "url": "/name/nm5156926/",
  "name": "Devon Downs"
},
{
  "@type": "Person",
  "url": "/name/nm2632302/",
  "name": "Kenny Gage"
}],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```php
$names = [];
$data = json_decode($json, true);
if (true === isset($data['name'])) {
    $name[] = $data['name'];
    return $names;
}
foreach ($data as $director) {
    if (true === isset($director['name'])) {
        $names[] = $director['name'];
    }
}
return $names;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{
    "director": [
          {
            "@type": "Person",
            "url": "/name/nm5156926/",
            "name": "Devon Downs"
          },
          {
            "@type": "Person",
            "url": "/name/nm2632302/",
            "name": "Kenny Gage"
          }
  ]
  }';

  $names = [];
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  if (true === isset($data['name'])) {
      $name[] = $data['name'];
      return $names;
  }
  foreach ($data as $director) {
    foreach($director as $itme){
      if (true === isset($itme['name'])) {
          $names[] = $itme['name'];
      }
    }

  }
  return $names;
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Devon Downs
    [1] => Kenny Gage
)
```